# How to check IAM Password Policies in the AWS using Boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, boto3

I am looking to get all the IAM user's password policies for all the users.

How to check [IAM](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/iam.html) Password Policies enabled or not for all the users in the AWS account using Boto3?

Comment: It is not possible since that information is not stored.

Comment: how about 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-account-password-policy.html

Answer (score 1):

The password policy is set at the account level, not for individual users.  You can use something like this:

```
In [1]: import boto3
In [2]: iam = boto3.client('iam')
In [3]: iam.get_account_password_policy()
Out[3]: 
{u'PasswordPolicy': {u'AllowUsersToChangePassword': True,
  u'ExpirePasswords': False,
  u'MinimumPasswordLength': 8,
  u'RequireLowercaseCharacters': True,
  u'RequireNumbers': True,
  u'RequireSymbols': True,
  u'RequireUppercaseCharacters': True},
 'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
 'RequestId': 'f9a8fc8e-fbfc-11e5-992f-df20f934a99a'}}
```

To determine what the current policy is for an account.  If you want to make sure all users adhere to your policy make sure you expire passwords periodically then users will be compelled to create a new password that is compliant with your policy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`iam_policy` module for Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/iam_policy_module.html) which aims to manage IAM policies for users, groups, and roles. It allows uploading or removing IAM policies for IAM users, groups or roles.

In [`iam_policy.py` file](https://gist.github.com/adamchainz/7f5834fbbfa8e72c48da#file-iam_policy-py) you can find some [`boto.iam`](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/iam.html) code examples. E.g.

```
current_policies = [cp for cp in iam.list_role_policies(name).list_role_policies_result.policy_names]
for pol in current_policies:
    if urllib.unquote(iam.get_role_policy(name, pol).get_role_policy_result.policy_document) == pdoc:
        policy_match = True
        if policy_match:
            # msg = ("The policy document you specified already exists "
            #        "under the name %s." % pol)
            pass
```